# why PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a model `Post` and each time a post is created I want a new instance of `Moderation` to be created at the same time.

So in post.rb I use the callback `after_save :create_moderation`
Then write a private method :

```
 ...
 include Reportable
 after_save :create_moderation

 private
 def create_moderation
    self.create_moderation!(blog: Blog.first)
 end
```

But when a proposal is created I get this error :

> > PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "moderations_reportable" DETAIL: Key (reportable_type, reportable_id)=(Post, 25) already exists. : INSERT INTO "moderations" ("blog_id", "reportable_type", "reportable_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "blog_type") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"

In reportable.rb I have :

```
  has_one :moderation, as: :reportable, foreign_key: "reportable_id", foreign_type: "reportable_type", class_name: "Moderation"
```

Then few other methods for reportable object.

Note that this issue doesn't happen when I run the create method in console.

**EDIT**

```
  create_table "moderations", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "reportable_type", null: false
    t.string "reportable_id", null: false
    t.integer "blog_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "blog_type", null: false
    t.string "upstream_moderation", default: "unmoderate"
    t.index ["blog_id", "blog_type"], name: "moderations_blog"
    t.index ["reportable_type", "reportable_id"], name: "moderations_reportable", unique: true
  end



create_table "posts", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "title", null: false
    t.text "body", null: false
    t.integer "feature_id", null: false
    t.integer "author_id"
    t.integer "scope_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "post_votes_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.index ["body"], name: "post_body_search"
    t.index ["created_at"], name: "index_posts_on_created_at"
    t.index ["author_id"], name: "index_posts_on_author_id"
    t.index ["feature_id"], name: "index_posts_on_feature_id"
    t.index ["proposal_votes_count"], name: "index_posts_on_post_votes_count"
    t.index ["title"], name: "post_title_search"
  end
```

Comment: show you migration as well please since this is a Database Error and not an ORM Error

Comment: @engineersmnky I edited my post

Comment: and this `t.index ["reportable_type", "reportable_id"], name: "moderations_reportable", unique: true` didn't give it away?

Comment: Sorry copy paste error

Comment: No error that line is still part of the database key constraints. I think you want to change the hook to `after_create` rather than `after_save` because `save` will be called on `update` as well

Comment: @engineersmnky That works thank you very much !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you've added a unique index to your database:

```
t.index ["reportable_type", "reportable_id"], name: "moderations_reportable", unique: true
```

With a unique index you will only be able to have one record with the same `reportable_type` and `reportable_id`. It's likely that you're trying to create a moderation for a reportable that already has a moderation.

Answer (score 108):

To fix the issue, we have to tell ActiveRecord to look at the sequence of the table:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('table_name')
```

Now ActiveRecord should have the correct sequence value, and should be able to assign new id's properly.

To resolve error

> PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "moderations_reportable" DETAIL: Key (reportable_type, reportable_id)=(Post, 25) already exists. : INSERT INTO "moderations" ("blog_id", "reportable_type", "reportable_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "blog_type") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"

As error occurred on 'moderations' table.

Run the following from **rails console** fix

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('moderations')
```

Thank you

Comment: You are champion my friend. Is this permenant solution?

Do you think this issue can come again?

Comment: Yes, But you need to reset the sequence if you mess it again.

Comment: you're right, do you have any automatic solution for it?

Comment: This saved my hide for something totally unrelated. Brilliant.

Comment: It's kinda life-saver answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 35):

Fix pkey sequences for all database:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table_name| 
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(table_name)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**ONLY FOR THOSE WHO ARE SEEING THIS WHILE RUNNING TESTS**

---

One possible reason is, you have some migrations that create new data-records and you ran one of the following recently.

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

or

```
rake db:migrate:reset RAILS_ENV=test
```

### Solution

You need to clean/wipeout your test-DB. Run this

```
rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test
```

This will wipeout and generate schema from `schema.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can also resolve your problem, Add this in your staging or preprod console ( I am using Heroku for this so I added in my heroku rails console)

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
connection.execute("SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('moderations', 'id'), MAX(id)) FROM moderations;")
```

Check out this [blog](https://blog.kiprosh.com/activerecord-recordnotunique-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint-key-already-exists/) for more info and how this is been generated