# PG::UniqueViolation error even when there is no duplicate key value. How to resolve this issue?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-11

I have a table called comms_applications and in my table i have an index

```
add_index "comms_applications", ["user_id", "gender", "deleted_at"], name: "index_comms_application_user_gender_active", using: :btree
```

I am certain i do not have a duplicate key value but i keep getting this error message when i try to update my table

> error: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates
> unique constraint
> "index_comms_applications_on_user_id_and_gender"\nDETAIL:  Key
> (user_id, gender)=(629, Female)

I tried dropping the index but still the error is still showing.

Is there a way for me to remove all data stored in an index for postgresql or anyway i can resolve this issue.

I am using Rails 4 with Postgres 11

Comment: could you please share your table definition as well ?

Comment: btw take a look at this, mostly similar problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577532/why-pguniqueviolation-error-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint
maybe a reset required during migration from ruby.

Comment: It seems that the violation comes from a different constraint - the error message includes only fields `user_id` and `gender`. There is no `deleted_at` in the message. Constraint name indicates the same: 
 it's `index_comms_applications_on_user_id_and_gender`, not  `index_comms_application_user_gender_active`

Answer (score 0):

I think this can also resolve your problem, Add this in your staging or preprod console ( I am using Heroku for this so I added in my heroku rails console)

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
connection.execute("SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('comms_applications', 'id'), MAX(id)) FROM comms_applications;")
```

Check out this [blog](https://blog.kiprosh.com/activerecord-recordnotunique-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint-key-already-exists/) for more info and how this is been generated