# How to insert the records into postgresql python?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I am trying to insert the pandas dataframe into postgresql table. What I am doing is inserting the record of dataframe loop by loop. I am recursively getting errors, Code is shown below:
**Code:**

```
    import psycopg2
    df = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv')
    
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "postgres",
                            user = "postgres",
                            password = "12345",
                            host = "127.0.0.1",
                            port = "5432")
    
    cur = conn.cursor()
    
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO stock_market_forecasting_new (date, open, high, low, close) \
          VALUES (df['date'][i], df['open'][i], df['high'][i], df['low'][i], df['close'][i])")
    
    conn.commit()
    print("Records created successfully")
    conn.close()
```

**Error:**

```
UndefinedColumn: column "df" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._new (date, open, high, low, close)       VALUES (df['date']...
```

**Edit1:**

I am doing like this,

```
cur.execute("SELECT * from STOCK_MARKET_FORECASTING")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
print("Operation done successfully")
conn.close()
```

Output giving:

```
('2021-12-07 00:00:00', 1.12837, 1.12846, 1.1279, 1.128)
('2021-12-07 01:00:00', 1.12799, 1.12827, 1.1276, 1.1282)
```

Output which I want should be with column names:

```
       **Date          open      high     low   close**
    ('2021-12-07 00:00:00', 1.12837, 1.12846, 1.1279, 1.128)
    ('2021-12-07 01:00:00', 1.12799, 1.12827, 1.1276, 1.1282)
```

Comment: side note, but you could also clean this up with `values = tuple(df[col][i] for col in df.columns)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't use a formatted string. It should be `f"VALUES ({df['date'][i]},"` ect depending on your data type, but that always leads to issues with quotation marks. I recommend inserting with tuples instead as seen in the [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries):

```py
import psycopg2
df = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv')

conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "postgres",
                        user = "postgres",
                        password = "12345",
                        host = "127.0.0.1",
                        port = "5432")

cur = conn.cursor()

for i in range(0 ,len(df)):
    values = (df['date'][i], df['open'][i], df['high'][i], df['low'][i], df['close'][i])
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO stock_market_forecasting_new (date, open, high, low, close) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                values)

conn.commit()
print("Records created successfully")
conn.close()
```

Alternatively, you could see if `df.to_sql()` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)) supports psycopg2 connections:

```py
df.to_sql('stock_market_forecasting_new', con=conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: It is giving error: UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "stock_market_forecasting_new_pkey"

Comment: That's an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577532/why-pguniqueviolation-error-duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint) with your database, not your python code. Is your primary key defined as [serial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)?

Comment: Toba, Can you please tell me that how can I view the column name with column contents using psycopg2 , I have edited my post

Comment: [blog post](https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/get-the-column-names-from-a-postgresql-table-with-the-psycopg2-python-adapter-756)